# Getting general information from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios

I would like to fetch data from the "phone", "sms" and "mail" app on the iPhone. What I want to fetch is the last call made to a certain number/person, last sms and last email send/recieved.

Is this possible, and by that I mean possible on a "allowed by Apple" manor.

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Comment: How would YOU like it if some random App on your iPhone picked up all your private call, sms and mail data, and sent it to who-knows-where without telling you?

Comment: I don't think I mentioned anything about not telling anything, but I see your point. I wouldn't have any problems with that, but maybe thats just me.

Comment: I looked into to this a bit for a client and found that it's quite doable on both Android and BlackBerry, and that there are many apps that do it, which was surprising. (And made me glad I use an iPhone, frankly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, that isn't possible using public APIs.

If you did want to use private functions (which would cause app store rejection), check out some of the private stuff in Core Telephony:

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/CoreTelephonyFunctions

Comment: I was afraid of that... but really needed this functionality. Bummer if apple rejects these functions. Argh!

Answer (score 0):

No, none of those things are possible using public APIs.